# Rotating dashed line in photoshop breaks dashes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a dashed line in photoshop, i then duplicate the shape and rotate 90 degrees but the dashed line is different and i don't know why.

This is how i setup my line:
[image]

And this is the visual issue i am getting when i duplicate and rotate:

[image]

How do i stop the dashed line from changing when i rotate it ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I can't recreate this problem. When I try, both dashed lines look the same.

Comment: How do i check which photoshop version i am on ? Maybe the version is the reason.

Comment: In Photoshop click *Help > About Photoshop*.